# How to obtain mysql dependencies between views?

Tags: mysql, sql, view, graph

I have a mysql database with more than 60 views, some auxiliary and some final. They have dependencies between them. This is giving me performance issues, of course, but I didn't design this database and system.

To speed up some reports I'm materializing the final views into tables. I could speed up this process by materializing the auxiliary views too, and then using them to materialize the others, sparing the re-processing of the auxiliary ones.

To do this I need a way to see the dependencies between views, so I can materialize the views in the correct order. It would be great if I could input that information to a graph (using tools such as Graphviz or Tikz, for example).

**Is there any way to do this besides manually analysing each view?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A separate view's query can be visualized in many query designers, but the whole views' structure in database stays unobservable.

- [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) and Oracle SQL Developer seem to render views as separate objects.
- [SchemaSpy](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/) renders views graph, which is based on field names, not FROM clause.

It's hard to manage ~50 interconnected views. I haven't found any comfort tool for that task yet.

Answer (score 5):

I used the following query to get the dependencies from the FROM clause:

```
SELECT  views.TABLE_NAME As `View`, tab.TABLE_NAME AS `Input`
FROM information_schema.`TABLES` AS tab 
INNER JOIN information_schema.VIEWS AS views 
ON views.VIEW_DEFINITION LIKE CONCAT('%',tab.TABLE_NAME,'%')
```

Then I feed the output to a python script that uses ete2 module to visualize the dependencies as a tree structure. I can share the script if anybody is interested.
Edit: Caution, I just realized, this query may cause problems if a view name is a substring of another view name. If any body can suggest improvement, please do.

Answer (score 3):

> Edit: Caution, I just realized, this query may cause problems if a view name is a >substring of another view name. If any body can suggest improvement, please do.

```
SELECT  views.TABLE_NAME As `View`, tab.TABLE_NAME AS `Input`
FROM information_schema.`TABLES` AS tab 
INNER JOIN information_schema.VIEWS AS views 
ON views.VIEW_DEFINITION LIKE CONCAT('%`',tab.TABLE_NAME,'`%')
```

I think the ` signs next to % does eliminate your sub string problem and some other problems. In practice this will work. Only problem that I see is when you have a database where some table names are the same as column names, but in a proper DB design this won't be the case.